# How to autolaunch after checking if process running in user's session

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have been working with the following (with different applications obviously):

```
@echo off
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq AutoHotkey.exe" | find /i "AutoHotkey.exe"

IF ERRORLEVEL 2 GOTO NEXTPROGRAM
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO LAUNCHPROGRAM

:NEXTPROGRAM
goto LOLLAUNCHER


:LAUNCHPROGRAM
start "" "C:\Program Files\AutoHotkey\AutoHotkey.exe"
goto LOLLAUNCHER

:LOLLAUNCHER
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq LoLLauncher.exe" | find /i "LoLLauncher.exe"

IF ERRORLEVEL 2 GOTO NEXTPROGRAM2
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO LAUNCHPROGRAM2

:NEXTPROGRAM2
goto COMPLETE


:LAUNCHPROGRAM2
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\League of Legends\lol.launcher.exe"
goto COMPLETE
```

I have this in a batch file that runs when a user logs in or unlocks the computer. That part works great, however, I need to take this a bit further.

Eventually this is going to be spread across several computers at an airport flight counter. Due to the nature of their job, they are telling me that they would potentially have multiple users using the same 3 applications on the same computer.

Being a security minded individual, I am instructing them to use individual logins so we can keep track of who is doing what on the systems. So I suppose my question is - how can I alter this to check for the process running in a particular users session rather than just on the computer itself? The issue is that if a user is logged in and has their applications running, and then steps away, but another user needs to jump on to that station to help out a guest, the script will run - identifying that processes are running but then do nothing. I need to edit this to check if the process is running for that user's session. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `/V` option to get tasklist to list username as well.
Then pipe the command into another findstr.
Example:

```
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq AutoHotkey.exe" /V | find /i "AutoHotkey.exe" | findstr /i %username%
```

`%username%` is a system variable and hence this finds the app for the currently logged in user.